# Yosemite hangs exactly every 60 minutes

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

Upgraded from Maverick. It froze every 60 minutes, **exactly** (yes, I timed it). Had to long press power button to force it to shutdown.

Then I erased the whole hard drive and did a fresh installation. No third party apps installed. Same issue.

The only way I found to get around this issue is: shutdown the computer 59 minutes (or less) after it boots, and then turn it back on. Clicking "Restart..." in the top left Apple logo menu doesn't help -- the 60-minute timer is still running.

Mid 2012 Macbook pro. The system is installed on an external USB3 SSD, not the internal SSD.

I've fired a radar with Apple a week ago. No reply so far.

Anyone has the same issue and/or know how to fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem with a 2011 macbook-air and I have the system installed on the internal SSD. So at least it seems that the model of the Macbook and the installation location are not the causes. Unfortunately, I can't find a solution yet either.

Comment: I fired a bug report to Apple a few days ago. No reply so far. They don't seem to care about this issue. Maybe just an edge case. The reason I created this post was to have an idea if this is really just an edge case.

Comment: I also tried installing on a 64GB 95MB/s SD card. Same issue.

Comment: Do you use Google Chrome by any chance? I heard there is also an issue with Chrome, in which processes hang in the background, and thus stacking them up after a while. This will make the MAC slower, and maybe, ultimately freezes your MAC? I'm trying out not to use Chrome and my MAC didn't crash for a while now.

Comment: I have a new MacBook Pro 2014 with internal SSD (512GB) and have noticed that after upgrading to Yosemite, the laptop hangs (beachball) for 30 secs and then comes back. This keeps happening. When I try finder, the directories doesnt show up immediately. Also when I startup Disk Utility in this state, this hangs as well. Rebooting seems to help for an hour or so and then back to the problems. This is frustrating as I just got this laptop a month back!!!

Comment: Is there any info in the logs? Use console.app to read them

Comment: Since upgrading to Yosemite, I have to power cycle my "MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)" every hour or two. I can still move the mouse cursor, and the Caps Lock light toggles when I press the key, but the computer is unresponsive in every other way. I'll look at the console logs next time it happens.

Comment: @dirk - I tried using Safari instead of Chrome, same issue. I don't think it is a problem of Chrome.

Comment: @Agos - I couldn't find anything suspicious in the logs. I didn't even see the "send crash report to Apple" dialog, which usually showed up after restarting from crash in previous versions of OS X.

Comment: My log showed a few "Received display connect changed" messages before each hang, so after looking at [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126299/switching-graphics-cards-with-the-screen-asleep-makes-windowserver-freeze) I tried turning Energy Saver / Automatic Graphics Switching off, and the issue has not recurred since. If you see that message in your logs too, it might be worth trying.

Comment: Did you try to do a PRAM reset? http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14222?viewlocale=en_US

Comment: Yes, I reset both SMC and PRAM. Didn't fix the problem. I am sure the PRAM succeed as I reset the sound volume. But I am not sure if the SMC succeed though. I didn't see "the LED on the MagSafe power adapter changed states or temporarily turned off"

Comment: @Ethan Same issue exactly. I didn't measure the intervals but I think they're also close to 1 hour

Answer (score 1):

Here come in depth solution that fixed same problem that I had, and maybe it will help you and others. First off all there is no magic wand solution for this, but I spend 3 days to fix it, and now it working 2 days with no freezing..

I have:
Mac (27-inch, Mid 2011), OS X Yosemite Public (installed from Maverick)...

Every 1-2 hours my Mac freezes, sometimes in PS, DropBox, Chrome, Creative Cloud... etc.. and I need to hard reset every time... also if I start doing "normal" reset or shutdown (if my mac is not in freezing mode), sometimes it only hangs with black screen and mouse working...

I tried:
- cleaning PRAM
- fix permission
- delete applications that sometimes craches
- remove logitech keyboard & mouse
- work only with safari, not chrome
- and nothing happens

Long story short...
- Boot you Mac in Safe mode, first.. it will take some time, and than start normal Yosmeite
- Then reset or shutdown, it needs to turn off really fast (30 sec max)...
- Than boot again only with Disc Utility (Command+R to boot into Recovery, or hold down OPTION), you cannot do this from Yosemite...
- Than Verify for errors, and fix those errors (approx. 2-3 hours of waiting)
- Again fix permisions..
- Yosemeith is working now, and don't freeze anymore...

Bottom line: Mac is really problematic with file handling, and if you had Maverick with lot's of install/uninstall applications, than Yosemite is even worse, so Fix disk errors, and everything will be ok...

Hope you will fix it this way..

Comment: I just tried your solution. Disk Utility said "the volume appears to be OK" so the process of verifying and fixing disk errors took less than 2 minutes. And my Yosemite still freezes exactly every 60 minutes.

Comment: Maybe you already done this, but did you tried to turn off Sleep (computer / screen)? It's so strange that excatly 60 minutes pass by from one to another freezen...

Comment: Yes, I did turn off sleep a few days ago.